# Is this a good solution to handle JavaScript (TypeScript) modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have been developing an e-commerce system with PHP and TypeScript. I really do not want to use any third-party module solution, like require.js, but I can't decide, my way is a good or a bad way. My solution is pretty simple. I export the class in the compiled JavaScript file as a module.

```
var Ajax = /** @class */ (function () {

}());

export default {Ajax}; //this is where I paste this code after compiling.
```

After that, I import in other files, and I export the other module.

```
import AJ from "./Ajax"; //this is here!! 
let Ajax = AJ.Ajax;

var UserHandler = /** @class */ (function () {

}());

export default {UserHandler}; //this is here!!!,
```

With this solution:

```
import AJ from "./Ajax";
let Ajax = AJ.Ajax;
```

I can use the Ajax variable as a constructor.

```
let ajax = new Ajax();
```

It's a very simple way to handle this problem, but is this a good, or a bad solution? What do you think?

Comment: This is a good solution if you know what you are doing. In this case, you are exporting an object containing just one property. Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you trying to find a way to bundle your JS? You  should not need to 'paste' any code.

Comment: I just want to export my class as a module. No, it's not "just one property" it is the whole class, in this way, I can use all of the methods. AJ.Ajax is the whole object, not just one property. I can export these classes (functions, whatever, module pattters) in an object, and therefore I have to use this syntax.

Comment: Why are they declared as variables, do you intend to reassign them during execution of the program? It seems fine, apart from that. I don't think you want them to be mutable, so `const`.

Comment: TypeScript has better options to handle the external data which ajax does. What is the value addition to do this?.

Comment: FWIW, you can also do `new AJ.Ajax()`, there is no need to assign the class to another variable. But exporting an object with a single property is odd. Why not just do `export default Ajax` and to `import Ajax from "./Ajax"`? No need for an "intermediary" object.

Comment: Oh, thanks man! I tried to this in typescript first, and the vscode says it's not okay, but in the javascript file this is OK, because in the js file there is no class just an object.